# Will Ubuntu Touch be avalible for all Android phones? what version will I need for installation?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Will Ubuntu touch be available to be used on any Android phone such as my Lg G2X p999 or is it just Nexes and Samsung? Also what version of Ubuntu will I need for Installation? I know that the full version of Ubuntu touch will be out in October, and if by that time if you will have anything available for the newer version of my phone, the LG G2?

Answer (score 0):

The primary target for Ubuntu Touch is dedicated handsets that come with the operating system.

As those don't exist yet, the [supported devices being used for development](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Supported_devices_and_codenames) are the Galaxy Nexus (GSM version), Nexus 4, Nexus 7 (2012 model) and Nexus 10.

Separate to this, there are [community supported ports](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices#Working.2C_but_not_available_from_cdimage.ubuntu.com) to some other existing devices.  If you are lucky, someone might do the work to create a port for your device, but it isn't guaranteed.